# Redirect stdin of powershell script to subprocess

Tags: powershell

In my scenario, I have a powershell script that receives standard input. What I would like to do is start a subprocess using an arbitrary command line and redirect the standard input from the powershell script to the subprocess. In other words, I simply want to pass down the standard input to the subprocess.

I have a few ideas on how to do this with loops, but is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Do you want to receive stdout back from your subprocess? If so the answer is considerably more complicated - because your script needs to wait on two things at once: stdin from the script and stdout from the subprocess. If you're not careful it is easy to hang script waiting on stdout if no output is forthcoming. But as a start suggest you look at .NET [system.diagnostics.process] to create the sub process and redirect it's stdin

Comment: In my particular case I don't need to wait for any return from the subprocess, but this information might be useful for future readers.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: `$input | & foo -bar`?

Comment: You might have some trouble with this in certain cases, because PowerShell.exe waits for all of the input before it even begins executing your script. I ran into an issue where a process calling PowerShell didn't close its stream so PowerShell waited forever. The solution was to use an undocumented option (`powershell.exe -InputFormat None`) and then read the input manually byte by byte (yes it had to be 1 byte at a time).

Comment: briantist If you write that as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a full answer, but you might have some trouble with this in certain cases, because PowerShell.exe waits for all of the input before it even begins executing your script. I ran into an issue where a process calling PowerShell didn't close its stream so PowerShell waited forever.

The solution was to use an undocumented option (`powershell.exe -InputFormat None`) and then read the input manually byte by byte; all methods that read more than 1 byte at a time are susceptible to blocking forever, at least as far as I could tell.

You could probably work around that with asynchronous methods.